# ETPush sales force notification not working in Android O

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, android, push-notification

I have used following code for notification but it is not working in android O.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
ETPush.configureSdk(new ETPushConfig.Builder(getApplication())
                                .setEtAppId(Environment.getSalesforceAppId())
                                .setAccessToken(Environment.getSalesforceAccessToken())
                                .setGcmSenderId(Environment.getSalesforceGcmSenderId())
                                .setNotificationResourceId(R.drawable.ic_notification_white)
                                .setOpenDirectRecipientClass(DeeplinkActivity.class)
                                .build()
                        , this                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

The version of the SDK that you are using does not support Android O.  Please upgrade to at least version 5.2.0:

http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/